# Holt Winters with exogenous regressors in R

Tags: r, regression, forecasting, exponential-smoothing

I need to forecast using `HoltWinters` with regression parameters using R. But I found there is not any option of `xreg` in `HoltWinters` function in R. I thought to use `auto.arima` with `xreg` option but my `HoltWinters` is performing better than `auto.arima` without any regression parameters.

Can you please suggest me how to incorporate `xreg` in `HoltWinters` function in R?

Comment: Including external regressors in exponential smoothing-type models is nontrivial. You would have to look up the newest works of Rob J. Hyndman and colleagues, they might be developing something in that direction, but I doubt there are any software implementations as of now.

Comment: See http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/ets-regressors/

Answer (score 5):

As [Richard Hardy comments](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/220830/holt-winters-with-exogenous-regressors-in-r#comment417753_220830), exponential smoothing methods like Holt-Winters typically do not allow for external regressors.

On the one hand, extending the state space framework in which `forecast::ets()` is fitted to incorporate external regressors should be straightforward. You may want to look at [*Forecasting with Exponential Smoothing - The State Space Approach* by Hyndman, Koehler, Ord & Snyder](http://exponentialsmoothing.net/). However, I do not know of any implementation, so you would need to code this up by yourself.

On the other hand, you could take inspiration from [the way `forecast::auto.arima()` actually models external regressors](http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/arimax/). Contrary to first impressions, this is *not* an ARIMAX model, but a regression with ARIMA errors.

This suggests a way forward: you could simply regress your time series against your regressors (using, say, `lm()`), and then run your favorite exponential smoothing model fitting algorithm (`stats::HoltWinters()` or `forecast::ets()`) on the *residuals* from this original regression. This would do something different from a true state space model, but it might be worth looking at.

(And if your Holt-Winters model gives you better results than `auto.arima()` with regressors, you may want to investigate your model and/or data a bit more. Perhaps your regressors are in reality not all that relevant. Or you have something else in your data that it hard to handle for `auto.arima()`, e.g., [multiple-seasonalities](/questions/tagged/multiple-seasonalities), missing data, long seasonal cycles or something similar.)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try  exponential smoothing model fitting algorithm on the residuals and also will investigate my data

Comment: It has been 3.5 years now since this post, do you have any new information on the subject? Do you still think this is feasible? Any implementations in R?

Comment: @user2974951: no, nothing new I am aware of. I would write the same answer again today.